# ¿Como hacer una consulta en MYSQL, que limite por fechas y anexe a las personas que no tienen registro?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas una donde almaceno Num. de empleado, Hora entrada y hora salida con "DataTime".

La otra tabla tiene la información completa del usuario  las combino.

Cuando extraigo y limito la búsqueda por una fecha en especifico me trae los datos pero me excluye a los usuarios que no tienen registro.

Dejo un ejemplo de mi consulta:

```
SELECT 
@Con:=@Con+1 nro, 
t.id, 
e.Empleado_No,
e.Nombre_Empleado,
e.Puesto, 
e.Departamento, 
t.Checada1, 
t.Checada2, 
t.Checada3, 
FROM employees_list e

LEFT JOIN  timeclok t
ON t.Empleado_No = e.Empleado_No, (SELECT @Con:=0) c

WHERE e.Departamento LIKE 'Maintenance'   
AND e.Estatus = 'Activo'  
AND t.Checada1 >= '2019-06-03 00:00:00'
```

Alguien podria decirme como hago aparecer los usuarios que no tienen registro de entrada o de salida.

Se ingresen en la consulta.

Para que se vea así:

```
 Nombre_Empleado | Empleado_No | Checada1 | Checada2
------------------------------------------------------
    Jose         |    0001     | 05:55:12 | 14:55:12
------------------------------------------------------
    Juan         |    0002     | 05:58:41 | 15:00:06 
------------------------------------------------------
    Manuel       |    0003     |          |  
------------------------------------------------------
    Diana        |    0004     |          |  
------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al poner la condición `where` eres tu mismo el que está excluyendo a los empleados que no tienen marcaje, pues al evaluar el `where` se van a incluir solamente los mayores a cierta fecha.

Si quieres ver todos los empleados, te sugiero aplicar esa condición como parte del `join` y no del `where`. Esto hará que los registros se filtren antes de hacer la relación entre las tablas. El `left` join nos asegura que se incluirán todos los empleados que cumplan las condiciones del `where`, aunque no tengan marcajes que cumplan las condiciones del `join`. En código sería así:

```
SELECT 
@Con:=@Con+1 nro, 
t.id, 
e.Empleado_No,
e.Nombre_Empleado,
e.Puesto, 
e.Departamento, 
t.Checada1, 
t.Checada2, 
t.Checada3, 
FROM employees_list e
LEFT JOIN  timeclok t
ON t.Empleado_No = e.Empleado_No AND t.Checada1 >= '2019-06-03 00:00:00'
, (SELECT @Con:=0) c
WHERE e.Departamento LIKE 'Maintenance'   
AND e.Estatus = 'Activo'
```